# Fetching data from one table and putting in other?

Tags: mysql, spring

I have to make an order table. The order table will be getting its data from the chart table which have customer id and item id. How can i do it

Comment: Please show us what you have done first.

Comment: and tables' structures too. if both matches you can do: `INSERT order VALUES(SELECT * FROM chart)`